# Parser to get fully bracketed syntax of a C code

Tags: c++, c, gnu

As a part of project, I am trying to develop a code detecting the region of a `for` loop given in C/C++ syntax. But this is much more complex that it looks! The parser should take care of the given `{`, one statement `for` loops, one statement `if-else` controls, and so on.

I wonder is there any stable tool (GNU is preferred) to make the C/C++ code fully bracketed?

Thanks in advance!

***Further information***

By the fully bracketed, I mean marking the scope of loop by `{` and `}`.

Example:

Input:

```
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    if (i % 2)
      j++;
    else
      j--;
```

Output:

```
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if (i % 2){
      j++;
    }else{
      j--;
    }
  }
```

Comment: try astyle -> http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Bracket_Style_Options

Comment: What are you going to do with the stuff inside the brackets if you're not writing a full parser?

Comment: I recommend [using Clang as a library](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/index.html#using-clang-as-a-library) to do your parsing for you.

Comment: @Najzero thanks! but the tool seem only handles one statement semi-column ending structures. It misses the sample in my question.

Comment: @Pubby I am developing a source-to-source code generator parallelizing the loop statements.

Comment: Maybe take a look at openMP sources?

Comment: If you're comfortable with _Regular Expressions_ than have a look at the _Quex_ parser http://quex.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @sftrabbit Thanks! I am going to use `clang-format` as the starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) with excellent results

> Features
>
> - Ident code, aligning on parens, assignments, etc
> - Align on '=' and variable definitions
> - Align structure initializers
> - Align #define stuff
> - Align backslash-newline stuff
> - Reformat comments (a little bit)
> - Fix inter-character spacing
> - Add or remove parens on return statements
> - **Add or remove braces on single-statement if/do/while/for statements**
> - Supports embedded SQL 'EXEC SQL' stuff
> - Highly configurable - 454 configurable options as of version 0.60

Comment: Great! Just what I want! Thanks.

Comment: Op says  *I am developing a source-to-source code generator parallelizing the loop statements.*   How on earth does this answer help?  It provides no access to the code structures or the meaning of symbols, without which you cannot "parallelize loops" or do any other non-trivial code manipulation.

Comment: @IraBaxter  1. It answers the question "I wonder is there any stable tool (GNU is preferred) to make the C/C++ code fully bracketed?" 2. The project is open source  3. It does what the OP wanted. 4. I am not associated with uncrustify (except as a user) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers  5. This question should probably be either a) updated to reflect his final solution or b) migrated to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ as it is not technically suited to the SO format (however softwarerecs did not exist at the time AFAIR)

Answer (score 1):

I could find the solution with [pycparser](https://bitbucket.org/eliben/pycparser). It is enough to modify the `visit_for` function defined in `pycparser/c_generator.py`. Then by running the built-in pycparser example (`example/c-to-c.py`) you'll get the fully-bracketed for-loops from a C code.

***For the future references, modifications are as follows:***

In pycparser, modify the `visit_for` declaration in `pycparser/c_generator.py` from:

```
def visit_For(self, n):
    s = 'for ('
    if n.init: s += self.visit(n.init)
    s += ';'
    if n.cond: s += ' ' + self.visit(n.cond)
    s += ';'
    if n.next: s += ' ' + self.visit(n.next)
    s += ')\n'
    s += self._generate_stmt(n.stmt, add_indent=True)
    return s
```

to add `{` before `self._generate_...` and `}` after it.